# Objective-c UIImage bad image quality

Tags: ios, objective-c, graphics, uiimageview, uiimage

I am not the best graphic designer, but need to setup few icons. I made them with gimp with options like Border, etc. All are primary designed in 1000x1000px and used in objective-c code in `UIImageView`.

I am wondering why resized icon look that terrible. Any suggestions?

In app:
http://s14.postimg.org/k2g9uayld/Screen_Shot_2014_12_18_at_11_22_53.png
http://s14.postimg.org/biwvwjq8x/Screen_Shot_2014_12_18_at_11_23_02.png

Original image:

Can't Post more than 2 links so:   s17.postimg.org/qgi4p80an/fav.png

I dont think that matters but

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fav.png"];
image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:25 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

But one of images has been set up in storyboard and effect is the same.

Comment: You are not respecting the actual resolution of the iOS devices, you must create all icons in respective resolutions like this http://www.iosres.com/ and too not to forget 1x, 2x, and 3x abbreviations, in your case I think you have got only fav.png where as an image fav@2x.png is required which will be automatically picked by os to display on retina devices, we have a new resolution 3 for iPhone 6 Plus devices, so you will need fav@3x.png image to make it look perfectly fine.

Comment: When you use i`mageNamed` you give it a name not file name. Comment above described the rest.

Comment: Second line with scale is insane, provide art with proper dimensions instead.

Comment: Im not sure if not using @2 @3 is the problem. I've tried also using 128px and this issue occurs on all devices

Answer (score 0):

```
    [self.favO.layer setMinificationFilter:kCAFilterTrilinear];
    [self.favO setImage:[self resizeImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fav.png"] newSize:CGSizeMake(35,35)]
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];

- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, imageRef);

    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

This fixed problem. This problem occurs while UIImageView takes care of resizing.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid this kind of behavior I suggest you make SVGs instead of png files. Using the lib SVGKit you can then resize it to your heart content. Since SVG format is a vectorial format there won't be any loss in your scaling.
https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit

EDIT:
To add up to this solution, your PNG file at 1000X1000px must be really heavy, on the other hand a SVG file is a text file so it makes it very lightweight

Comment: Is this only possible way? i just need to set up few icons, i will definitely use this in next project.

Comment: I guess the more simple way to go around this is to make smaller images so that the scaling won't be as painful as it must be for CPU now. have you try to provide different images size and watch the results ?

Comment: Has nothing to do with original question

Comment: Well I guess I was trying to give a more flexible flexible solution

Comment: ive tried using 128x128px and the result was exactly the same, that's why i've tried 1000x1000